# How do I make an Infragistics WinForm Grid to allow only a single row to be selected?

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

How do I make an Infragistics WinForm Grid to allow only a single row to be selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set following properties of grid control.

> MultiSelect=False
>
> SelectionMode=FullRowSelect